# How can I modify source code using Python-Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently using Selenium on Python to automate some stuff, and what I'd like to do is modify a specific part of an element on the source code when inspecting it.

Specifically, I want to replace `Blur(12px)` in the following code to `Blur(0px)`, to remove the blurriness of the pictures:

```html
<div class="Bdrs(8px) Bgz(cv) Bgp(c) Ov(h) StretchedBox Ir(p) Cnt($blank)::a StretchedBox::a Bg($inherit)::a Scale(1.3)::a Scale(1.2)::a--s Blur(12px)::a" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://preview.(...).com/); background-position: 50% 100%; background-size: auto 100.952%;"></div>
```

I am not too sure of how this can be done, and although I have done my research I was not able to find a proper solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript to make the attribute change.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("... some css selector ...") # this can be however you want to find the element
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class', 'Blur(0px)')", element)
```

This is assuming you are using the variable 'driver' for your webdriver object.

The html sample you gave had a lot of other classes in your class attribute.  If you want to retain the rest, you can get the attribute contents first, replace the Blur(12px) with Blur(0px) and then use this for your value in the javascript line.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("... some css selector ...") # this can be however you want to find the element
class_value = element.get_attribute("class")
revised_classes = class_value.replace("Blur(12px)", "Blur(0px)")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class', arguments[1])", element, revised_classes)
```